# How much should I share my thesis dissertation with advisers while writing?

Tags: phd, thesis, collaboration

As I begin writing up my work in earnest during my final year of a PhD  in computer science, I'm wondering about how much and how often to share my work-in-progress thesis dissertation with my advisers.

I'm asking in the sense of what's healthy / sensible.  There must be a balance between the "present soon, present often" mantra and the "deep work/flow" approach.  The former might avoid wasting efforts if I spent a month writing something which then needs tearing up and starting again but it might mean there is frequent re-thinking and tweaking at the expense of getting a significant chunk done.

I am used to collaborating on papers "live" using [Overleaf](https://overleaf.com) or git so that all stakeholders can at least see (and usually contribute to) the progress of the project.  I know lots of people use things like Google Docs or equivalent with the ability for a reviewer to comment on sections.  I guess in the olden days you'd print off a chapter at a time and hand it in, hoping it came back with (just the right amount of) scribbles on it from your adviser.

I am also aware that PhD thesis is very much about one's own contribution and is not a group project (in terms of writing at least).  So I appreciate that if the advisers had access, we would need to have clear "ground rules" in terms of them just pointing things out that need work.

I'm interested in people's experiences. What worked well?  Any pitfalls to avoid?

Comment: Likely depends a lot on the current state of your work, your advisors, and how busy everybody is. Most of my thesis was published already and my advisor did not worry about it too much.

Comment: This seems like a question you should ask your supervisor, as the only answer that's relevant to you is the one they think is correct.

Comment: @astronat I think you're right to a large degree although it's MY thesis and up to me to be ready.  My advisers are accommodating, so in a sense it's up to me to agree something that's sensible or likely to work well for me.  I'm also interested in other people's perspectives.

Comment: Right, but in that case only you knows what works well for you :) Think about the speed at which you write and when your deadline is. Work out roughly how long it will take you to write a good first draft of each chapter, say x weeks. Ask your supervisors if they are happy to review 1 chapter every x weeks. Adjust your writing speed according to their answer. My personal advice is don't give yourself too much time. It won't take you a year to write your thesis. Think more on the timescale of 2-3 months, especially if you have published papers which will become chapters.

Answer (score 3):

This requires a consultation with your advisor. The best thing is to work out something, whatever it is, that is mutually agreeable.

Certainly, though, consult with them when you are stuck and can't seem to get unstuck. Consult with them when you have major insights that might lead to other things or a better overall result.

They may or may not want to see the actual writing periodically, but an update every week or two on progress is pretty typical.

But don't hold it back until their acceptance of your work becomes critical and some disagreement at a late date sets you back. I've seen that happen.

Answer (score 0):

My advisor and I emailed LaTeX files back and forth. We even had a macro for his comments to appear in the margins. So he could edit or make a comment. Now there’s Overleaf, so you’ve got version control, too, and email is out of the loop. That seems less annoying. If you can both handle LaTeX, I’d recommend trying a chapter In Overleaf. If that doesn’t work, try some other co-editing software.